# How to check if java byte size exceeds database column size

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I've recently implemented a patch on pop3worker daemon that removes mails that has `infoVO.getRcvName().getBytes("UTF-8").length > 200` : For rcvname that exceeds the 200 byte size limit in db (SQL Server) column size.

However I still have data trying to INSERT into the database when it should have been removed by WAS from the patch I've implemented.

Only when I change to `infoVO.getRcvName().getBytes("UTF-8").length > 150` it starts to work. But I remove mail that has the exact column size. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: "stupid question": is the column UTF-8? (i don't know a more reliable way to get the byte count of a string in java)

Comment: can you live with `infoVO.getRcvName().getBytes("UTF-8").length() > 199` ?

Comment: This is the column type : rcvname (nvarchar(200),Null)

Comment: Actually that was my suspicion at first so I checked whether the db would accept length()=200 sized values. And it worked. So I don't think 199 vs 200 would make a difference

Comment: Aren't [Java strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) UTF-16 encoded, same as [nvarchar columns in SC collations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql)? Why the conversion to UTF-8 to check the length?

Comment: The default value for infoVO.getRcvName().length() measures UTF-8 encoded values. which results in the same length as infoVO.getRcvName().getBytes("UTF-8").length so I guess it doesn't make much difference converting to UTF-8. Could this be affecting the insertion somehow? I have a local and operating db both using mssql and with the same encoding and column size/setting. But this code works on the local db but not on the operating DB.... I've looked for setting differences but this doesn't seem to be the case